# A better linear model has less precision(relative to the worse model) at a larger threshold

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, python, precision-recall

I trained two models using the same algorithm - logistic regression (`LogisticRegression(max_iter=180, C=1.05)` for ~27 features and ~330K observations). I used the same features for both models, except six additional feature for the second model. When I use the threshold 0.5, the second model has better precision than the first model(which has fewer features), but when I set the threshold to 0.6 then first model is better than the second. I use k-fold with 11 folds for validation.

How is it possible? And how can I achieve better precision with the second model?

**UPD**

I checked the precision recall AUC for both models. AUC for the first model = `0.56821`, for the second = `0.56814`. So, according to PR AUC I got a worse model.

I also checked feature importance using this code:

```
kbest = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=1)
kbest.fit(df[additional_x_columns], df['target'])
print(kbest.pvalues_)
```

And got this:

> [6.56951599e-01 4.17353178e-40 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
> 2.21697597e-93 9.36746822e-03]

So, most of them are significant.

How can I get worse model with these features?

**UPD2**

[image]

Comment: Do yourself a favour and plot the precision recall curves for each model on the same graph. Then read them out and pick the relevant thresholds. There a lot of things that might happens but for starters monitoring performance on a hold-out set can be very enlightening.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for your response! Could you check the updated question?

Comment: Since the difference in AUC is 0.56821 - 0.56814 = 7e-05, isn't a better question whether, at this stage, either model is good enough for your purpose?

Comment: @dipetkov the shape of the curves still matters. We might have significantly different profiles, that is why I suggested looking at the curves themselves.  If anything so similar AUCs suggest we should look at the shape if we need to choose one of the two.

Comment: @usεr11852 I agree. It's also the case that the OP has 330k observations, so even small differences in performance can be shown to be meaningful. It will help if the OP provides more information.

Comment: @dipetkov model isn't good enough yet

Comment: @usεr11852 I updated the question with PR curves

Comment: Thank you for adding them; as we see "second/orange" model is marginally better if we are in 60%+ Recall region, and vice versa marginally worse in the 40%- Recall region. You can plot where the 40-50-60 threshold cut-off per model will place onto this curve and then pick the one more relevant to your context. Also: 1. check what is going on with those misclassifications early on causing the spiking, maybe they are mislabeled data, 2. if the model is not good enough yet, and given you seem to have a lot of data, maybe you try a more expressive learner? (e.g. GBM) (+1 BTW)

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks! Do you mean spike down? Good idea, I'll check it out. I've already tried using more complex models, but logistic regression still has better performance, perhaps due to the linearity of the data. But I still can't figure out why adding these features makes the model worse? I tried to add target variable as predictor feature and got perfect result. So, the problem is in the features. I also checked that features are correctly calculated. What else can I check about the features?

Comment: Yeah, up and then down. :) Maybe do some additional feature engineering then and/or get more (relevant) explanatory variables.

Comment: @usεr11852 but I got pretty low p value for these features. Also, one additional feature has a high correlation coefficient - 0.11, when basic features have 0-0.08

Comment: This kind of correlations based filtering do not account for feature interactions so I don't trust them a lot.

Comment: @usεr11852 ok, what would you suggest to check if features are really good? What specific metric or technique should I use?

Comment: Use a regularised model (e.g. elastic net, LightGBM, etc.) and let all relevant features be included if they matter.

Comment: @usεr11852 got it! I think it's also useful to use [feature selection methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)